# VueJS - One component but make requests to 2 different addresses

Tags: vue.js

I have a component MainTable that renders a table in which I display Tasks:

```
({title: String, body: String, etc.}).
```

This component also triggers `created` method hook to make a request to my API to `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/tasks`.

I want to have a button with a link (route) to all `complete_tasks` where I want to also render the same table (hence I made it a component) with all complete tasks.

This time however, I want this component to make a request to a different address to `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/tasks/complete_tasks` (to fetch all complete tasks).

Is it possible to achieve this?

```
//App.vue

<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <h2>Todos</h2>
      <mainTable></mainTable>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import MainTable from './components/MainTable.vue'
  export default {
    components: {
      'mainTable': MainTable
    },
    methods: {
    }
  }
</script>

//MainTable.vue

<template>
  <table class="table table-sm table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Content</th>
        <th colspan="3"></th>
        <th><select-all-button></select-all-button></th>
        <th><finishButton></finishButton></th>
        <br>
        <th><removeAllButton></removeAllButton></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="task in tasks">
        <td>{{ task.title }}</td>
        <td>{{ task.content }}</td>
        <td><a href="#">Show</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">Edit</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">Delete</a></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>
<script>
  import SelectAllButton from './buttons/SelectAll.vue';
  import FinishButton from './buttons/FinishButton.vue';
  import RemoveAllButton from './buttons/RemoveAllButton.vue';

  export default {
    components: {
      'select-all-button': SelectAllButton,
      'finishButton': FinishButton,
      'removeAllButton': RemoveAllButton
    },
    data(){
      return {
        tasks: []
      }
    },
    created(){
      this.$http.get('tasks').then(function(data){
        this.tasks = data.body.slice(0,20);
      })
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, of course, you can do it
you can make a method trigger on click
when you press the button make a request to your endpoint and get the data
and update your object tasks with new data
Is that clear?

Comment: I know that but my case is special. I have a component which I want to render in two different routes. Let's say that on page load I render the component and I also have a button 'Complete tasks' which takes me to another route where I also render the same component but different tasks. On page load I make request to address '/api/v1/tasks' to fetch the data and display them in the component. On the 'complete tasks' route I also render the component but this time I want to make a request to '/api/v1/tasks/complete_tasks' and fetch the data and render them in the component. Does it make sense?

Comment: I understand you,

Comment: in the frontend, you want for example go to '/route1' open the component say 'X' with request to  '/api/v1/tasks' .... also go to '/route2' this open component 'X' with request to '/api/v1/tasks/complete_tasks' right? @jedi

Comment: Exactly! This is what I need.

Comment: Actually, I am thinking if I even need the route at all...I could perhaps have a button that would simply fetch data that I need, make it an active button, and then change the state of the table with new data...so the component stays the same but only the data changes.

Comment: how about making the routes with names and make check on the route name if the route is 'route1' make request to '/api/v1/tasks'  else make request to  '/api/v1/tasks/complete_tasks' in the same component?!

Comment: you got it or would you like to make an example for you?

Comment: I can handle that :)

Comment: Ok, go ahead, if you found my answer useful make it up